# JBoss EAP 6.2 not keep deployed WAR files

Tags: jboss-eap-6

We are deploying war files using Jboss EAP 6.2 administration Console and successfully deploy all war files. But the war files are not in jboss/standalone/deployments directory. Is there any option to deploy war files using Jboss administration console while keeping deployed war files in the deployments directory

Comment: The WAR files are kept in the container. What is the reason you'd like them in the deployment directory?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The reason raised while setting up Jenkins CI environment with JBoss EAP. 
I already find the solution.
When we deploy an application via the admin console or via the CLI, the application content will always be found at the /jboss-eap-6.2/standalone/data/content/ location.